# Is it possible for a system to identify hand signs using just the Haar training in OpenCV?

Tags: object, opencv, computer-vision, detection

I am doing a project on hand sign recognition on a static image. Can I use just Haar training to accomplish this?

As what I've understood, it is somewhat similar to the concept of neural networks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using Haar training maybe help to detect the hand, but not for recognize.

The people use many approaches, so I cannot give a unique. You could make some research using Google Scholar and use the keywords "hand sign", "recognition" and "detection".
Some tips: you need to segment the hand and use some template matching or other method to recognize the format. There is also a project for hand gestures [here](http://www.movesinstitute.org/~kolsch/HandVu/HandVu.html).

Comment: have you tried the application? seems like it isn't detecting my hand.

Comment: I did not tested the application. Try to get a hand classifier in xml format or try to email an author of a paper that used it.